# Is there a way to get a list of places based on a specific location in Android Development?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I've been looking at the Places API from Google for this, but I don't know if this is the right direction to take. The project revolves around finding a list of places based on a specific location, other than the current location (for instance, what kind of restaurants are around your friend's house (based on longitude and latitude)). Most of what I've seen with the Places API involves using the user's current location. Is there a way to pass in a predetermined location? Or can I fool it into thinking that location is my current location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think still places is the best option for you, you have to really understand the api to get what you need from it. Look at how could you send a request to the places api with a given location (long, ltd) and it will return nearby places.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-find-place#locationbias